# AndroidAnnotations RestService Post Image

Tags: android, android-annotations

I'm trying to upload an image along with additional data about the image, but having no luck.  I have tried many variations and always end up with `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.  How do I use AndroidAnnotations/Android Spring to post an image to my server?

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://api.me.com/v1", converters = FormHttpMessageConverter.class)
public interface CheckInService {
    @Post("/stuff/{id}/schedule")
    void checkIn(String id, MultiValueMap schedule);
}
```

Calling code:

```
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> values = new org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();
    values.add("image", new FileSystemResource(_selectedImageUri.getPath()));
    values.add("departure", schedule.departure.getTime());
    values.add("arrival", schedule.arrival.getTime());
    values.add("location[latitude]", schedule.location.latitude);
    values.add("location[longitude]", schedule.location.longitude);
    _checkInService.checkIn(id, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FormHttpMessageConverter` handles `Resources` subclasses (like `FileSystemResource`). And your `MultiValueMap` defines `Object` as values type. So, this should works.

Two things then :

- Did you tweak the configuration of `FormHttpMessageConverter` ?
- Could you give us the full stack ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue, fixed it by explicitly defining the generic type of the MultiValueMap inside the Rest Interface

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://api.me.com/v1", converters = {FormHttpMessageConverter.class
  StringHttpMessageConverter.class, ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface CheckInService {
   @Post("/stuff/{id}/schedule")
   void checkIn(String id, MultiValueMap<String, Object> schedule);
}
```

Also be sure to include any other appropriate converters. You will need the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.class for the FileResource and at least the StringHttpMessageConverter.class to convert the extra information to a string.